# How Up Navigation works

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've implemented inside my app the Up Navigation button in this way, inside my `AndroidManifest.xml` I wrote this:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".EventDetails"
        android:label="@string/category_events"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
</application>
```

I didn't do anything else and everything works very good.

I read the official documentation and about the

```
  android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
```

they say:

> With the parent activity declared this way, you can navigate Up to the appropriate parent using the NavUtils APIs, as shown in the following sections.

This is my child activity code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class EventDetails extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set the content of the activity
        setContentView(R.layout.event_details);
    }
}
```

So you can see that I don't implement NavUtils APIs, etc...

Now my question is this, why everything works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NavUtils are a set of convenience methods for doing certain tasks, like launching your parent as a new task.  They are not required for any android app, and there is basic functionality like back stack navigation present without any need to use them.

Also, I see you tagged this fragments-  it has nothing to do with fragments.  NavUtils is about navigating between Activities, not Fragments of a single Activity.

Comment: Clearly explained.